# How can I loop over a query for a specific number of times that may be greater than the result?

Tags: coldfusion

I need to loop over a query exactly 12 times to complete rows in a form but rarely will the query return 12 rows. The cfquery endRow attribute doesn't force the loop to keep going if the result is < 12. If it did that would be ideal to use something like cfloop query="myQuery" endRow="12"...
The 2 options that I have now are to skip the loop and write out all 12 rows but that results in a lot of duplicate code (there are 20 columns), or do a query of queries for each row which seems like a lot of wasted processing.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: If your query returns 6 rows what would you want the column values for the last 6 rows to be?

Comment: form fields with no value set. For example, if a user wanted to edit a saved invoice that has 12 rows in it, the first 6 get populated from the query when they pull it up and the next 6 would not have a value, so the user could put a value in them and save it or submit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
maxrows="12"
```

Although, I think there might be something wrong with your logic for having to do that. perhaps if you post some of our code, i can take a look a suggest a better approach.

maxRows will do the trick for now though

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention, maxrows have to be used with "cfoutput query", as cfloop query won't support it.

In this case you'll do somethig like:

```
<cfoutput query="myQuery" maxRows="12">
```

**UPDATE of UPDATE**

After understanding exactly what you wanted, I wrote the following code which is pretty much what I reckon you need:

```
<cfscript>
    qryTest = QueryNew("name,email");
    newRows = QueryAddRow(qryTest,5);

    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'name', 'John', 1);
    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'email', 'John@email.com', 1);

    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'name', 'Paul', 2);
    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'email', 'Paul@bob.com', 2);

    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'name', 'George', 3);
    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'email', 'George@bob.com', 3);

    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'name', 'Ringo', 4);
    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'email', 'Ringo@bob.com', 4);

    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'name', 'Yoko', 5);
    tmp = querySetCell(qryTest, 'email', 'Yoko@bob.com', 5);
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#qryTest#">

<form name="test">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="12" index="ii">
            <cfif ii GT qryTest.recordCount>
                <cfset tmp = QueryAddRow( qryTest, ii)>
            </cfif>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name_#ii#" value="#qryTest.name[ii]#"><br />
            Wmail: <input type="text" name="email_#ii#" value="#qryTest.email[ii]#"><br /><br />
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</form>

<cfdump var="#qryTest#">
```

This will add new rows to your query dynamically should it be necessary (i.e. in case you don't have 12 rows on your recordset)

It's mimicking a recordset just so you can copy and paste the code and see the results.

hope it helps  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I question my logic all the time;) Doing a cfoutput with maxRows gives you the same thing as cfloop query with endRows in that those attributes determine the max number of returns but won't mandate that at least that many rows get returned. As far as the logic goes: A simple use case would be for an invoice that a user could edit but would show some blank rows in addition to what they had ordered in case they wanted to add another item manually.

Comment: Humm I understand it now, and kinda think my answer does not make much sense now. I'll update my answer with some more code :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Now I have 2 better ways to deal with this!

Comment: Works great, thanks again! I changed it up a little bit so I wouldn't have to index all my variables but the QueryAddRow was the trick.
    <cfset rows = qxSessRow.recordCount>
   <cfset max = 12>
   <cfset blanks = max - rows>
   
   <cfif rows LT max>
                <cfset tmp = QueryAddRow( qxSessRow, blanks)>
            </cfif>
   
   <cfset n = 0>
   <cfoutput query="qxSessRow" maxrows="12">
         <cfset n ++>

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about column values you could try something like this...

```
 <cfquery NAME="testQuery" datasource="#DB#" >
    SELECT 
       SOMETHING 
    FROM
      SOMETHING
 </cfquery>

 <cfif testQuery.recordcount LT 12>

   <cfset temp = QueryAddRow( testQuery, 12- testQuery.recordcount)>

 </cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tested a variation of this concept taking the recordcount of the query minus 12 and making that a variable for the first loop and then making another loop for the remaining rows. It's rough right now but I think it can work.